# Finding an Eigen Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_2(F)$ and let $ T: M_2(F) \rightarrow M_2(F)$ be the linear transformation $T(X) = AX$

Let $\underline{0}\ne \underline{v} = (a_1, a_2) \in F^2$ be an eigen tuple of $A$. Find an eigen vector $\underline{u} \ne \underline{0}$ of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=\left(\matrix{a_1\\a_2}\right)$

By hypothesys, $V\neq 0$ and there exists $\lambda \in F$ such that $AV=\lambda V$

Let $Y=\left(\matrix{a_1 & a_1\\a_2 & a_2}\right)$

which can be considered as $\left(\matrix{V & | & V}\right)$

$T(Y)=AY=A\left(\matrix{V & | & V}\right)$

By definition of matrices product:

$T(Y)=\left(\matrix{AV & | & AV}\right)$

$=\left(\matrix{\lambda V & | & \lambda V}\right)$

$=\left(\matrix{\lambda a_1 & \lambda a_1\\\lambda a_2 & \lambda a_2}\right)$

$=\lambda Y$

Moreover $Y\neq 0$

To have a base which diagonalizes T, it is necessary to find 4 eigenvectors for T, linearly independent. But instead of placing a column twice, as before, we take one and place a column block of 0 (left or right).

Let $V_1=\left(\matrix{a_{1,1}\\a_{2,1}}\right)$

and $V_2=\left(\matrix{a_{1,2}\\a_{2,2}}\right)$

such that $(V_1,V_2)$ is a basis of eigenvectors for A.

Let's note $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ the associated eignenvalues.

Let $Y_{1,1}=\left(\matrix{a_{1,1} & 0\\ a_{2,1} & 0}\right)$,

$Y_{1,2}=\left(\matrix{ 0 & a_{1,1}\\0 & a_{2,1}}\right)$

$Y_{2,1}=\left(\matrix{a_{1,2} & 0\\ a_{2,2} & 0}\right)$,

$Y_{2,2}=\left(\matrix{ 0 & a_{1,2}\\ 0 & a_{2,2}}\right)$

We verify that they are engenvectors for T

$T(Y_{1,1})=AY_{1,1}=A\left(\matrix{V_1 & | & 0}\right)$

$\left(\matrix{AV_1 & | & A0}\right)$

$=\left(\matrix{\lambda_1 V_1 & | & 0}\right)$

$=\left(\matrix{\lambda_1 a_{1,1} & 0 \\ \lambda_1 a_{2,1} & 0}\right)$

$=\lambda_1 Y$

It is the same for the others.

Finally it remains to show that they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question means "Find the eigenvalue associated with the eigenvectot v."
Take the equation $$ Av= \lambda v $$ and take the dot product on both sides with v.
Then divide by v.v, which is not 0, since v is not the zero vector.
$$ \lambda=((Av).v)/(v.v) $$